# Excel formula gives unexpected result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

Each year I create a workbook within which there are several worksheets corresponding to each month of the year. I copy and paste the same table with formulas into each new month as the year progresses. I have never had any issue with the formulas therein, except most recently.

The column with the numerical values is formatted as such - numbers to 2 decimal places. As you can see below the cell D11 is set to `=SUM(D7:D10)` this is works correctly. The cell D12 is set to `ROUNDUP(D11,1)` this works correctly. The adjacent cell G12 is set to `=(D12-D11)`, which as far as I understand should calculate 372.60 - 372.59 = 0.01. However, the result shown is 0.02? Why is this? In previous months there has been no issue with this formula, please help me understand what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what number is actually in D11--setting a column to 2 decimal places does not round the number to two decimal places for the purposes of calculation, only for display--suppose the number in D11 was actually 372.585--which would be *displayed* as your 372.59. Now, actually rounding 372.59 to one decimal place with `ROUND(D11,1)` will result in the 372.60 your screencap shows. But 372.60 - 372.585 = .015, which, because you have column B set to show only two decimal places, will be displayed as .02.

Comment: Thank you both (James Norris & Robert Longson) for your swift replies. You have both unequivocally provided an explanation and mechanism for me to solve this issue. I have chosen to rewrite the formula in cell D11 to read "=ROUND(SUM(D7:D10),2)" which gives me the correct result in cell G12. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

- It seems like IGV is 18% of the the sum of (D7:D9). That's actually 56.835 but when displayed to 2 decimal places as you're doing it rounds up to 56.84.
- The value in D11 as the sum of the above numbers is then actually 372.585, again displayed to 2 decimal places that's 372.59
- The difference is actually 372.6-372.585=0.015 and when you display that to two decimal places you see it as 0.02

So be careful of displaying values to two decimal places, they may not always be exactly what you think they are.

You probably want to round the IGV value to 2 decimal places in the calculation. I.e. =ROUND(SUM(D7:D9)*0.18,2)